# Not able to run Az commands on Azure Runbook

Tags: powershell, nuget-package, azure-powershell, azure-runbook, az

I am trying to run the Az commands inside PowerShell type Azure Runbook. At starting it does not recognize the Az commands and want me to install NuGet. Now error displayed while installing NuGet.

```
#Set strong cryptography on 64 bit .Net Framework (version 4 and above)
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type DWord

#Set strong cryptography on 32 bit .Net Framework (version 4 and above)
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type DWord 

#Install NuGet
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force

#Uninstall AzureRm
Uninstall-AzureRm

#Install Module
Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts -Force
Install-Module -Name Az.Resources -Force

#Import Module
Import-Module -Name Az.Accounts -Force
Import-Module -Name Az.Resources -Force

#Connect to your Azure Account
$Account = Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Cred

Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName "test"
```

**Error**

```
Install-PackageProvider : No match was found for the specified search criteria for the provider 'NuGet'. The package provider requires 'PackageManagement' and 'Provider' tags. Please check if the specified package has the tags. At line:17 char:1 + Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Power...PackageProvider:InstallPackageProvider) [Install-PackageProvider], Exception + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForProvider,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackageProvider
```

**Multiple Errors**
[image]

If you notice that my **Connect-AzAccount** run successfully but **Get-AzResource** throw error.

1. Is it necessary to install NuGet?
2. How my **Connect-AzAccount** does not throw an error.
3. My **Uninstall-AzureRm** is failing but if I don't use it then it throws a different error.

   Get-ChildItem : AzureRM.Profile already loaded. Az and AzureRM modules cannot be imported in the same session or used in the same script or runbook.
4. Is **Get-AzResource** required some other module to import?
5. There is no issue at my local machine. Having an issue in runbook only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The environment of runbook is different from that in local, if you want to use `Get-AzResource`, please follow the steps below.

**Note**: Please make sure you created the `Run As Account` when you created the automation account like below.

[image]

1.Navigate to the automation account in the portal -> `Modules` -> `Browse Gallery` -> search for `Az.Accounts` and `Az.Resources` -> `Import` both of them. The latest version of `Az.Resources` has a dependency of `Az.Accounts>=1.8.0`, if you have already have the old version of `Az.Accounts`, just remove it and install the newest version, then install the `Az.Resources`.

[image]

2.Then use the script below in the powershell runbook.

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    Connect-AzAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName "<group-name>"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works. Actually I am trying to import the modules using commands but it should be imported through automation account Modules gallery. Also, there was no Az.Resources imported for my automation account.

Comment: Adding one more thing. First, you need to import modules in the automation account. Second, you also need to import it in your script too.